# trapezoid approximation of sine function

Tags: optimization, approximation, periodic-functions

I want to find a **reasonable good periodic trapezoid function approximation for the sine** (or cosine) function.

My use case is it to **divide the year in 4 epochs**:

1. visible light length stays roughly the same (around winter solistice),
2. visible light lenghtens by roughly x minutes a day (around spring equinox),
3. visible light length stays roughly the same (around summer solistice),
4. visible light length shortens by roughly x minutes a day (around fall equinox).

I'd be interrested in **3 values**:

- length of visible light during quasi-contant epochs
- steepness of change in the transit epoch
- days of transition between the epochs

If I did not make a mistake, this requires estimation or calculation of **two parameters** of the trapezoid function: **amplitude** and **one of** either **lenght** in high or low phase or **steepness of the transition**. Additionally of course some **weighting function** to establish a minimum distance would be required. If sensible/possible I'd go for sum of **absolute difference**.

I tried to establish a picewise formula for the difference between sinus and a periodic trapezoid function, to then minimize this, but it was over my head. Unfortunately I am not fluent enough in a mathematical program language to state that problem. **Before I do a brute force numerical approximation** I'd rather have a closed symbolic expression that yields a nice and exact solution.

Comment: I assume you mean "sine" and "cosine", I've never heard them called "sinus" and "cosinus" before. The question that needs to be asked is what criterion you want to use to determine a "good" approximation. The two obvious choices are to either minimize the maximum difference between function values, or else to minimize the area between the two curves. But which would you prefer? Or is there some other criterion that would be better in this case? There is no need to "brute force" it. Either way, the problem is not hard to solve analytically.

Comment: @PaulSinclair. These are the French names of these functions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: of course sine and cosine, I'm used to the German terms, which in turn stem directly from the Latin "Sinus" for "bend; bay", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Etymology for details.
The measure for the quality of the approximation would be the minimum sum of absolute distance, equal to the minimum absolute area between both functions.
Hard is in the eye of the beholder, and I got stuck and are happy for every hint that someone may offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:
[image: piecewise linear approximation to a sinusoid]

This is the line $y = x$ up to some maximum point $c$, which it maintains until it gets to $\pi - c$, where it drops by the line $y = \pi - x$, etc. We can control $c$ to determine the best fit.

The simplest criterion to find the best fit for is the minimum height difference between the two curves. The trapezoidal curve (the usual term of art for this sort of curve is "piecewise linear") is highest above the sine curve at $x = c$, where the distance is $c - \sin c$. The sine curve is highest above the trapezoidal curve at $x = \pi/2$, where the distance is $1 - c$. The distance will be minimized when these two distances are equal, so $c - \sin c = 1 - c$. Wolfram Alpha computes this to be when $c \approx 0.887862$.

If you want to minimize the area, that calculation is a lot more complex. By symmetry, it is sufficient to look only at the portion between $0$ and $\pi/2$, where  the area is given by
$$A = \left(\int_0^c x\,dx + \int_c^{\sin^{-1} c} c\,dx - \int_0^{\sin^{-1} c} \sin x\, dx\right) + \left(\int_{\sin^{-1} c}^{\pi/2} \sin x\, dx - \int_{\sin^{-1} c}^{\pi/2} c\,dx\right)\\=\frac{c^2}2 + c(\sin^{-1}c - c) - (1 - \cos(\sin^{-1}c)) +  \cos(\sin^{-1}c) -c(\frac{\pi}2- \sin^{-1}c)\\=-1 - \frac\pi 2 c - \frac {c^2}2 +2\sqrt{1 - c^2} + 2c\sin^{-1}c$$

To minimize the area, we take the derivative with respect to $c$ and set it to 0:
$$A' = -\frac \pi 2 - c -\frac{2c}{\sqrt{1 - c^2}} + 2\sin^{-1}c + \frac {2c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}=2\sin^{-1}c-\frac \pi 2 - c = 0 $$
Which Wolfram Alpha says is $c \approx 0.95261$.

Of course, I just used $y = \sin x$, whereas your curve will need to be of the form $$y = A\sin(Bx)$$ but the same solution should work using lines of slope $\pm AB$, and a cutoff value of $C = Ac$ for your choice of the two $c$ values calculated above.

Comment: You might do a little better (for some definitions of better) by allowing the slope to be slightly less than $1$.  That is one more parameter, which makes the trapezoid wave more complicated but can improve the fit.  Well done.

Comment: @RossMillikan - I had considered that, but of course, the best linear approximation to sine at the inflection points is slope $1$, so I left it and just controlled the height.

Comment: @RossMilikan: I got to the point of just looking at the 0 to \pi and establishing the function for the area, but it never occurred to me that I could just start with one parameter and let the slope be the trivial one. Great step by step solution, learned something about solving problems by starting small and simple.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: how do you produce the nice graphics?

Comment: [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). It took me some work to figure out how to do the trapezoid curve, through.